# Custom Label Renderer in Xamarin Forms: OnDraw never fired

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, ondraw, custom-renderer

I'm trying to customize how some Labels get rendered in a Xamarin Forms project. More specifically, I'm trying to do custom drawing on the control.

For this purpose I created a custom renderer where I overrode OnDraw method.

I can use my label in xaml code, it shows and code in OnElementChanged inside custom rendrer is executed.

Unfortunately, my OnDraw function is never called.

I found many references to this situation on Google (and StackOverflow), but I'm still unable to solve the problem.

This is my shared project code:

```
public class CustLabel : Label
{

    public CustLabel()
    {
        // THIS IS WORKING: LABEL HAS RED TEXT
        TextColor = Color.Red;
    }

}
```

This is the custom renderer code:

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyApp.CustomRenderers.CustLabel), typeof(MyApp.Droid.CustomRenderers.CustLabelRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CustLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {

        public CustLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            this.SetWillNotDraw(false);
        }


        // I DON'T ACTUALLY NEED OnElementChanged, I USE IT JUST TO SEE IF LABEL GETS CUSTOMIZED IN SOME WAY
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                // THIS IS WORKING: LABEL HAS AQUA BACKGROUND
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Aqua);
            }
        }


        // THIS IS NEVER EXECUTED
        protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
        { // <-- BREAKPOINT HERE, NEVER REACHED
            base.OnDraw(canvas);

            var paint = new Paint();
            paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Blue;
            paint.StrokeWidth = 2;

            canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, 10, 10, paint);
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

File `CustLabelRenderer` seems ok, just check once `ExportRenderer`.  Your `CustLabel` class should look like this, in your shared project

```
 public  class CustLabel : Label
 {
 }
```

Now use `CustLabel` in your **`xaml`** like this

```
<localPath:CustLabel  
   HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="Something"
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

Declare `localPath` like this in your top xaml tag. `xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:MyApp.CustomRenderers.CustLabel"`

Be careful while declaring `localPath`.

Now it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm able to use the label in xaml code, it is displayed and the sample customization made in the shared project is working. Also, the custom renderer gets called: sample customization in OnElementChanged is properly applied. The only thing that is not working is OnDraw (which is also the only one I really need). I updated my question to better clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a result of my running screenshot.

[image]

I changed `StrokeWidth` from 2 to 20, and `canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);`

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    { // <-- BREAKPOINT HERE, NEVER REACHED
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        var paint = new Paint();
        paint.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Blue;
        paint.StrokeWidth = 20;

        canvas.DrawLine(0, 0, 100, 100, paint);
    }
```

And changed the `CustLabel`

```
   public class CustLabel : Label
{


}
```

Your CusLabel set the `BackgroundColor` to `Aqua`, `paint.StrokeWidth` is too small and `DrawLine` is too short. Paint was coverred by BackgroundColor, here is running screenshot.
[image]

Here is my demo, you coud refer to it. Hope it can help you.

https://github.com/851265601/CustomizeLabel

Comment: @Disti Do you have any updates? If the reply help to you, please mark the reply as answer.